# How to use sizeof in other function (from pointer)?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Let's provide an example. I have one main file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "otherfile.h"

char output[1024*10];

int main(){

    writeSomething(output);

    return 0;
}
```

and another file with the function:

```
void writeSomething(char *o){
    printf("sizeof(o)=%d", sizeof(o));
    //code
    memset(o,0,sizeof(o));
    // code
}
```

While compiling this, I got the warning:

> argument to 'sizeof' in 'memset' call is the same expression as the
>   destination; did you mean to provide an explicit length?

What I want is to set the whole `output` array to `0` in my function, so all 1024*10 bytes. But because I pass it as a pointer, it will only set the first 8 characters to `0` (because `sizeof(o)=8`).

How can I memset the whole array trough a pointer? Is that even possible?

Comment: To do this you need to send the size explicitly to the function. Do, `writeSomething(output, sizeof(output))`

Comment: use `strlen(o)-1` instead of `sizeof(o)`

Comment: @AbdulGafoor I dont think that its necessary that it is a string. Maybe it wont be nul terminated .

Comment: Global variables are auto-initialized to zero

Comment: @CoolGuy you're right, but this is a minimal example of my problem. In my real code, `output` is first filled and then it sometimes has to be 'emptied'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when passed as the argument to the function, the array decays into a pointer and information about its size gets lost.

Redefine the function to

```
void writeSomething(char *o, size_t sz){
    printf("sizeof(o)=%d", sizeof(char) * sz);
    //code
    memset(o, 0, sizeof(char) * sz);
    // code
}
```

so that the call to it looks like `writeSomething(output, 1024*10);`.

As pointed out in the comments, the C99 standard requires that `sizeof(char)` be `1`, so it's fine to omit the `sizeof(char)` in the code I provided. However, I prefer to leave it there for stylistic reasons.

Comment: This is good, but `sizeof (char)` is always 1 so that part is pointless and just adds noise. Also the proper way to print values of type `size_t` is using `%zu`.

Comment: I know that `sizeof(char)==1` by the C99 standard, but I find it more "correct" to see that sizeof(char) there. It tells me that the programmer knows he's allocating the memory for `char`'s.

Comment: Its not just C99 where `sizeof(char)` is one. In all the C standards, it is one.

Comment: I don't about pre-C99; I know that as of C99 it is 1. Thanks for noting.